# ErrorException Attempt to read property "name" on null (View:

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-8

Tengo 2 relaciones que apuntan a un mismo modelo User:
operador() y profesional()

```
class Cita extends Model
{

    public function paciente(){
        
        return $this->belongsTo('\App\Models\Paciente');
        
    }
    
    public function profesional(){
        
        return $this->belongsTo('\App\Models\User');
        
    }

    public function operador(){
        
        return $this->belongsTo('\App\Models\User');
        
    }
    
}
```

En la vista las llamo así:

```
                        @foreach ($comisiones as $comision)
                            <tr>

                            <td>{{ $comision->paciente->name }}</td>
                            
                            <td>{{ $comision->profesional->name }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $comision->operador->name }}</td>
                            
                            <td>{{ number_format($comision->total, 0, '.', '.') }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $comision->estado }}</td>
                            </tr>
                        @endforeach
```

El programa se me cae cuando intenta llamar al $comision->operador->name.
Si lo dejo como comentario funciona sin problemas.
Pero me da error cuando tengo las 2 relaciones al mismo tiempo.

¿Puedo tener 2 relaciones apuntando al mismo modelo?. Y si no se puede, que alternativa tengo?.
Gracias

Comment: Hola... y porque tienes 2 relaciones distintas que apuntan al mismo modelo con las mismas claves local/foráneas? tendría mas sentido si la clave local/foránea fuera distinta para ambas relaciones

Comment: Las tengo porque en la tabla users almaceno los datos de usuarios de distintos perfiles, como son Operador y Profesional.

Comment: Buen día, intenta decirle a la relación qué columnas están relacionadas `return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'columna_externa', 'columna_interna');` En columna externa pones la columna del modelo usuario y en columna interna la columna del modelo Cita, si te funciona avísame para poner la respuesta

Comment: @HeytalePazguato Así me funcionó `return $this->belongsTo('\App\Models\User', 'operador_id', 'id');.`. Gracias

Comment: @EduardoTapia, Agregué la solución con la explicación completa de los parámetros con el fin de ayudar a otros usuarios que tengan la misma pregunta, si la respuesta te sirvió, por favor acepta la respuesta con el fin de ayudar a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas.

Comment: @HeytalePazguato gracias por la respuesta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

La respuesta es con el fin de que la pregunta quede resuelta con la conclusión de los comentarios anteriores en tu pregunta

Con el fin de ser claro como se llego a la solución explicaré los diferentes parámetros que tiene una relación `belongsTo`

Cuando usas relaciones `belongsTo` normalmente usamos un solo parámetro que es la clase con la que se va a relacionar el modelo. En tu caso relacionar el modelo "Cita" con el modelo "User"

```
$this->belongsTo('\App\Models\User');
```

Si no hay más parámetros, Laravel automáticamente busca relacionar la columna que se conforme con el nombre del modelo y concatena `_id` en tu caso sería `user_id`

Hay ocaciones que queremos relacionar otra columna y entonces podemos utilizar el segundo parámetro de la relación para hacerlo, por ejemplo en tu caso sería

```
$this->belongsTo('\App\Models\User', 'operator_id');
```

Sin embargo, en ocaciones especiales (Como en este caso donde un modelo, "Cita", tiene dos columnas que se relacionan con el mismo modelo, "User") podemos utilizar el tercer parámetro de la relación para indicar qué columna externa se relaciona con qué columna interna

Según la [documentación de laravel 8](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships) los parámetros que recibe `belongsTo` son de la siguiente forma:

```
return $this->belongsTo(Model::class, 'foreign_key', 'owner_key');
```

En tu modelo cita, la columna que tiene un parámetro externo es `operator_id` y la columna del modelo usuario que deseas relacionar es `id`

Tal como mencionas en tu comentario la solución sería:

```
return $this->belongsTo('\App\Models\User', 'operador_id', 'id');
```